# Android how can I set a TextView content inside a TableView

Tags: android, textview

I have a Table with some TextView inside.
I click one of them for `startActivityForResult` and take in input the data and put it into a pressed `TextView`.
The problem is that I have 60 `TextView` inside this Layout.
How can I set the clicked `TextView` with the results that I take with `onActivityResult`?

XML:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat11"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro" />
```

ActivitySetOrario.java

```
public class ActivitySetOrario extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;
//Static perche cosi non perdo i dati inseriti in precedenza!
static Data DB = new DataBase();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);

}//Fine oncreate

//Prende indietro la materia aggiunta dall'ActivityAddMateria
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
            int color = data.getIntExtra("color",1); //Take the color from Dialog

            Materia materia;
            materia = new Materia();
            materia.setMateria(result); //put the name materia into class materia
            materia.setColor(color); //put the color materia into class materia
            DB.getMaterie().add(materia);
   //******HERE I NEED TO TAKE THE ID OF THE CLICKER AND SET TEXT WITH RESULT AND BACKGROUND FROM COLOR******
          }

        } 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Nessuna materia inserita
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_set_orario, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.draw_orario:
        //addMateria();
        return true;
    case R.id.save_data_orario:

        backToOrario();
        return true;     
    case R.id.exit_orario:
        //Torno alla schermata orario annullo ogni modifica NON SERIALIZZO
        backToOrario();
        finish();
        return true;     
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Torna alla ActivityOrario
public void backToOrario(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityOrario.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void addMateria(View v){
    //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the logcat output for the crash?

Comment: `02-24 19:52:29.951    9402-9402/com.ddz.diarioscolastico E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method addMateria()(View) in the activity class com.ddz.diarioscolastico.ActivitySetOrario for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'mat11'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
            `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `addMateria` method is not declared properly so Android cannot link the onClick action.

Try changing

```
public void addMateria(){
    //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this,ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
```

To

```
public void addMateria(View v){
    //To get your TextView do this
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) v;
    //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this,ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
```

Comment: Ok now the activity dialog start, but i don't know how put the input data to the textview that call the method addMateria(View v).

Comment: That's a different question entirely with several solutions. http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: I don't need to store it, my question is how can i get the id of the TextView that call the method addMateria(), because i have 60 TextView that can call it.
If i use getId, which id i receive back? How can i use it?

Comment: TextView thePressedTextView = (TextView) v;

Comment: I showed you how to get the TextView so you can set the data, you'll need store the textview somewhere then pass the data from new Activity back to the original Activity that has the list then you can set the TextView.

Comment: I put the entire code of the Activity, as you can see with the onActivtyResult i take back the input, i put it into my Data class.
But now i need to change the text of the clicked TextView with the variable result that contain the input text.

Comment: ActivityAddMateria, needs to send the data back to ActivitySetOrario instead of starting a new ActivitySetOrario Activity, which is what the Non-Persisent Object section of the link in my 2nd comment describes. It's not a simple process and it goes beyond the scope of your original question. Please accept the answer and create a new question describing your new problem.

Comment: The data is send back with the `onActivityResult` with the variables  `String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); int color = data.getIntExtra("color",1);` .
To my origina post i ask "How can I set the clicked TextView with the results that I take with onActivityResult?"
If you know how help me i don't open another post.
If you are not i can't accept the answere because you help me to solve the crash.
Thank you.

Comment: And what I'm saying is you are doing it wrong, you are starting a new activity so your stack looks like this: Activity1 -> Dialog -> Activity2. Activity 2 may change the text but Activity 1 won't have the changes, if the user hits back twice from Activity2 the changes won't be reflected. I have given you a link to documents showing how to send data back to an activity and shown you how to get the TextView you want to change. I won't code your whole project for you. This isn't a place to get free work. I answered your questions.

Comment: If you send the Materia object back to your Original activity, you can call a function when you close the dialog that sets the TextView that you have saved in your original Activity.

Comment: Sir I only make a question that you aren't solving. Don't be angry with your "This isn't a place to get free work" i don't write here for this.
I put a question and i don't find a solution. Maybe i write wrong my question or maybe not.
Have a nice day a thank you for solving crash problem.
Bye

Comment: I'm not angry but frustrated because you have clearly stated what you are trying to do and I have explained to you how to do what you are trying to do but you say it is not an answer because it is not the way you are trying to do it. The way you are trying to do it won't work.

Comment: There are many resources and tutorials that you can use and the solution you need no longer fits in the context of this Question and Answer.

Comment: I may have figured out what you wanted to tell me. I have posted here the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708166/android-how-set-a-clicked-textview-with-the-input-data 

And one user give me some advice if you want check and if you want be sure about that you say (because now i need to store the passed data or i lose it at the next textview click) i can accept your solution here.
Thank you and don't be frustrated i'm only new with android and java.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to tell you, you need to maintain your information somewhere and share it so that it's not lost. My advice would be to store a list of your text and colors somewhere and store it somewhere your activity can access it and when you finish your dialog go back to the original activity instead of starting a new one.

Comment: Ok, now i understand what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not able to resolve the addmateria class on click view.
http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-5%E2%80%93Adding-Multiple-Activities-and-using-Intents
This would help you out.
find a method addMateria()(View) or if it is not there declare it in the intent you are calling.

Comment: android:onclick itself calls the method . you have already used in textview it will work fine.
Please upvote or check this as answer if you are satisfied.
Thankyou