# Android how set a clicked TextView with the input data

Tags: android, textview

i have a Table of `TextView` (60 TextView), the user can touch them and set the text and the background of the clicked `TextView`.
When one `TextView` is clicked this event open a `DialogActivity` with `startActivityForResult` and take back two variables (string and color).
My problem is how set the text and the background of the clicked TextView with the input variables that are returned by `onActivityResult`?

Some code there
Activity

```
package com.ddz.diarioscolastico;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivitySetOrario extends ActionBarActivity {

//Static perch� cosi non perdo i dati inseriti in precedenza!
static DataBase DB = new DataBase();
static int clickedTextViewId; // Declare TextView as class level member field


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);

}//Fine oncreate

//Prende indietro la materia aggiunta dall'ActivityAddMateria
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
            int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

            Materia materia;
            materia = new Materia();
            materia.setMateria(result); //put the name materia into class materia
            materia.setColor(color); //put the color materia into class materia
            DB.getMaterie().add(materia);
            // Now use mTextView  here
            //View view = findViewById(clickedTextViewId);
            TextView clickedtextView = (TextView) findViewById(clickedTextViewId); //(TextView) view;
            if(clickedTextViewId == clickedtextView.getId()) {
                clickedtextView.setText(result);
                clickedtextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Nessuna materia inserita
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_set_orario, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.draw_orario:
        //addMateria();
        return true;
    case R.id.save_data_orario:
        //SERIALIZZO I DATI CHE DOVRA PRENDERE ActivityOrario
        //FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        //os.writeObject(this);
        //os.close();
        //fos.close();
        backToOrario();
        return true;     
    case R.id.exit_orario:
        //Torno alla schermata orario annullo ogni modifica NON SERIALIZZO
        backToOrario();
        finish();
        return true;     
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Torna alla ActivityOrario
public void backToOrario(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityOrario.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void addMateria(View v){
    //To get ID of your TextView do this
    clickedTextViewId = v.getId();
    //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
}
```

activity_set_orario.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue_orario"
android:id="@+id/table">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/dayrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Lun."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mar."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mer."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Gio."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ven."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sab."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</TableRow>
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrollorario"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/prima_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?       android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat11"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat12"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat13"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat14"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat15"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat16"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/seconda_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat21"
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat22"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat23"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat24"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat25"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat26"
                      android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/terza_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/quarta_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/quinta_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/sesta_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/settima_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/ottava_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/nona_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/decima_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have to either maintain TextView's ID from `addMateria(View v)` or use direct `TextView`.

There are many ways to keep it like, class level variables etc.,

Like, declare `TextView` as a Class level member field.

```
public class ActivitySetOrario extends ActionBarActivity {

  //Static perch� cosi non perdo i dati inseriti in precedenza!
  static DataBase DB = new DataBase();
  int clickedTextViewId; // Declare TextViewId as class level member field

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);

 }/
```

Now, get reference of clicked Textview to mTextView in `addMateria(View v)`

```
 public void addMateria(View v){
        //To get ID of your TextView do this
       if(v instanceOf TextView) 
       {
        clickedTextViewId = v.getId();
       }
        //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
        ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
    }
```

Again access `mTextView` in `onActivityResult()`, to update color and Text

```
//Prende indietro la materia aggiunta dall'ActivityAddMateria
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int color = data.getIntExtra("color",1); //Take the color from Dialog

                Materia materia;
                materia = new Materia();
                materia.setMateria(result); //put the name materia into class materia
                materia.setColor(color); //put the color materia into class materia
                DB.getMaterie().add(materia);
               // Now use mTextView  here

              try
             {
               View view = findViewById(clickedTextViewId);
                  if(view instanceOf TextView)
                 {
                   TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                   textView .setText(result);
                   textView .setBackgroundColor(color);
                 }
             }catch(Exception ex)
             {
                ex.printStacktrace();
             }
             } 
             if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Nessuna materia inserita
            }
    }//onActivity
```

Comment: this is the log error 
`02-25 00:47:42.241  20159-20159/com.ddz.diarioscolastico E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity     
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode`
The app crash

Comment: Ok. Means you can not use Id as Request Code. As it has lower bit size only. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, i have back the id of the TextView Clicked but i don't know why `mTextView.setBackgroundColor(color);` change the color of all TextViews in the table....

Comment: @Dario - Without complete code, I can't tell you anything.

Comment: What do you need? The xml and the Dialog Activity that i call for take result?

Comment: Added, for test the java i added only to id mat11 the function onclick.
The problem is that using `if (ClickedTextView != null) {
                    ClickedTextView.setText(result);
                    ClickedTextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                }`
The text don't change, and background change to all textviews!

Comment: I add the new .java file with your suggestions. I must use `static TextView ClickedTextView = null;` or the app crash without static

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)' to  `try
             {
               View mTextView = findViewById(clickedTextViewId);
                  if(mTextView instanceOf TextView)
                 {
                   mTextView.setText(result);
                   mTextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                 }
             }catch(Exception ex)
             {
                ex.printStacktrace();
             }
             } `
Because the mTextView is a `View mTextView` and not a `TextView mTextView`

Comment: @Dario - Ohh Sorry.. You have to cast `view` to `TextView` first. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Nothing change when i set color and text from the dialog activity...i don't know why.
Now i add an update of the code that i have.

Comment: ok i solved a part of the problem. If i don't set the variable `int clickedTextViewId; // Declare TextView as class level member field` with the `static` when i come back to this activity from the dialog i lose my id and the app can't find the clicked textview.
With static i don't lose the id, but i think that if i don't store this data when i click another textview i lose the old data.

Comment: loaded the new code, now work without `try`  `catch` and `instaceof` i can use directly the `TextView`. And the `clickedTextViewId` with `static`.
Now i need to store this data or i lose the inputed string and color.

Comment: @Dario - Store in `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`.